# Overlay left click in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to overlay the left click by doing the following thing : when I left click on an element I want to remove the standard behavior and I want to apply my own function.

For now I wrote the following code but it doesn't work like I want. My function is executed but the standard behavior is kept :

```
window.opener.addEventListener("mousedown", myFunction, false);

var myFunction = function(Event)
{
    if(Event.button == 0)
    {
        var element = Event.srcElement||Event.target;
        aFunction(element);
        Event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Now the problem is that the preventDefault() doesn't work.

Regards.

Comment: Try returning false from `myFunction` as well as changing the third parameter of `addEventListener` to `true`. Does that work?

Comment: If you're checking for `srcElement`, you should also probably normalize `Event` like: `Event = Event || window.event;`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Returning from `addEventListener` has no effect like `.onEVENT` (or jQuery) handlers might. Changing the third parameter isn't a bad idea though :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it doesn't work ^^'

Comment: @lan you may have right but it doesn't change nothing too

Comment: @user2302725 Sorry, I should've mentioned I didn't mean it would fix anything; just that it's something you usually do for IE support. But I realized it's not even necessary for `addEventListener`

Comment: It's very frustrating this kind of problem ^^'

Comment: @user2302725 Maybe create a fiddle illustrating the issue?

Comment: @user2302725 On a side note, I hope that in practice the function is either defined in a function declaration `function myFunction(...` or it is _above_ the `addEventListener` otherwise it wouldn't work (it wouldn't be defined yet)

Comment: Maybe, I'm searching how to solve my problems. Thanks all for the help you brought to me :)